# Trying to install PCIe M.2 SSD but this Disabled my PCI-E Wireless LAN Card

Tags: wireless-networking, ssd, motherboard, pci-express

I recently bought and installed an Intel M.2 PCIe SSD. After installing and switching the BIOS setting for the PCI Express X4 slot to M.2 mode (which I had seen in a tutorial), I found that my Asus PCI-E Wireless LAN Card was no longer recognized. The motherboard I'm using is an Asus Z97-A ATX LGA1150 Motherboard. I did a little troubleshooting and found that switching the BIOS setting is what caused the problem since when I switched it back, then my wireless began to work again. However, now my M.2 SSD was no longer recognized. Is there an easy solution to have both operating? I am a relative novice and don't know much about the different slots on my motherboard. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The [user manual](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1150/Z97-A/e9060_z97-a_ug_for_web_only.pdf) for that motherboard states:

> The PCIe x1_1/2 slots share bandwidth with M.2 Socket 3. The M.2 Socket 3 is disabled by default

This means that you can only enable the M.2 socket, or the PCIe 1x slots. They share the same physical bus.

Move your WiFi card to a large PCIe slot, such as the one at the very bottom of the board. It will still fit and that slot does not share a bus with the M.2.

Comment: Thank you! I will definitely give this a try as soon as I get some free time